# Strange JSON in CouchDB

Tags: json, couchdb

I am learning CouchDB I and like its functionality very much. One things bugs me, though, and it is the claim that CouchDB communicates through JSON.

Actually, JSON requires that the keys for objects are strings, while [it is possible](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Introduction_to_CouchDB_views#Complex_Keys), and even [advised by Damien Katz himself](http://www.cmlenz.net/archives/2007/10/couchdb-joins) to have views which return objects whose keys are other objects, or arrays.

This is confusing, since I did not find written anywhere that CouchDB uses a variant of JSON. Moreover, it does not make much sense, for at least two reasons:

1. when are two keys considered equal? For instance, I assume that if CouchDB allows keys which are not strings, numbers would be allowed. But then the keys `5` and `'5'` will be different, which is weird since in Javascript they are considered the same.
2. More importantly, parsing the output of CouchDB will be more difficult, since one cannot use the standard JSON parsers which are available for every language.

> Am I just confused in interpreting the above links, or does actually CouchDB return a non-standard JSON output? And if so, how do one works with it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't get confused between keys of an object and keys of a couchdb view.

Each row in the CouchDB view result contains id, key and value. `id` is a string and `key` and `value` can be any object. It is very common to have non-string values as keys.

Here is a sample view result with non-string keys.

```
$ curl http://127.0.0.1:5984/blog/_design/posts/_view/by_date
{"total_rows":3,"offset":0,"rows":[
{"id":"88e325c07e897f52766340dc17003322","key":[2010,10,13],"value":null},
{"id":"88e325c07e897f52766340dc17002641","key":[2011,4,5],"value":null},
{"id":"88e325c07e897f52766340dc1700233e","key":[2011,4,23],"value":null}
]}
```

Comment: I now understand: I assumed that `key` and `value` were actually keys and values for a JSON object, instead they are both values. I find this naming convention misleading. What is there to distinguish the key from the value? One could put all information in the key. Moreover, once key and value are given the same status, there is really no reason `emit` has to emit two fields instead of any number.

Comment: Key and value are **not** given the same status in a couchdb view. The view is sorted by the key and you can associate arbitrary value with each key. It is possible to specify a reduce function that works on the values.

Answer (score 5):

**Document IDs** (the `_id`) field must be a string. **View keys** (the first parameter to `emit()`) may be any JSON value. You are right, it is a bit confusing.

Two keys are considered equal according to the [CouchDB collation specification](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/View_collation#Collation_Specification). Basically, values compare like you would expect:

- Numbers sort by value
- Strings sort according to the libicu rules.
- Arrays sort by comparing first value, second value, etc.

Of course, with *document IDs*, the only thing that matters is how strings sort since document ids are always strings.

Finally, CouchDB always outputs standard JSON. If you encounter nonstandard JSON from CouchDB that is a bug and the community would want to hear about it.

Comment: Correct, except for one thing: the default collation for strings is *not* lexicographical because of ICU. So, for instance, `aa < Aa < ab` which is impossible for a lexicographical ordering.

Comment: I am even more confused. Are you saying that CouchDB outputs JSON containing keys which are - for instance - arrays **and** that CouchDB outputs valid JSON?

Comment: Andrea, CouchDB always outputs valid JSON. You will never see an array as a JSON key. **View keys** are different, they are full JSON objects themselves (which are of course well-formed.)

Comment: The answer of Anand explains my problem. I assumed that the keys returned by views were actually keys of a JSON object, while, the object has a key `"key"` with the view key as a **value**.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this explains it.

[image]

On the second thought, keys are parts of map/reduce operations, so I'll have to dig into that.

Comment: Yes, you are not allowed to enter non string keys. But you get them in return when you use map/reduce. Should have mentioned it.

Comment: That may also be a Futon bug. Futon auto-detects the type of the data you input. It thinks you want the *number* 1, which is invalid. However, using HTTP directly (using ajax, or a standalone client), you could have a *string* `"1"` id, no problem.

Comment: @jhs: Futon fields are actually JSON fields which assume that if the content is not valid JSON, it is a string literal. Since `1` is valid JSON it is kept as such. You can always write `"1"` (it will not be turned into `"\"1\""`).

Comment: `1` is *invalid* as a CouchDB document ID. It might be nice for Futon to use `"1"` since at least that is valid. (Some people might say, don't quietly change the value, which I agree with usually.)